# How to get back default upper right corner notifications?

Tags: 11.04, unity, notification

I recently installed Xubuntu/Xfce session using Ubuntu Software Center in order to test how Xfce would look like.

I didn't like it, so I removed those packages and got back to the default Unity shell. But now the notifications that appear in the upper right corner no longer look like they should. Instead of that default transparent black design now there is a grey window, like this:

[image]

(This is an example from Pidgin, I don't know if it has some importance).

Everything looks ok but those notifications. What can I do to have back the original style?

Comment: Install `libnotify-bin` and run `notify-send foo bar` - does this result in a normal notification? Try purging the package `xfce4-notifyd` (`sudo apt-get purge xfce4-notifyd`). Does that make any difference (not sure if you need to log out or reboot, just do that to be sure).

Comment: I removed `xfce4-notifyd` but now I don't get any notifications, even if I installed `libnotify-bin` (and running `notify-send foo bar` doesn't do anything) :-s

Comment: Good, so you were missing Ubuntu's notification daemon. Install `notify-osd` and try again.

Comment: that's exactly what i did just now and wanted to answer my question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I did a better search I found that I was missing the `notify-osd` package. After I installed it everything went back to normal :)

Answer (score 0):

...So a full answer would be:

- Purge (uninstall) `xfce4-notifyd`. Command: `sudo apt-get purge xfce4-notifyd`
- Install `notify-osd`. Command: `sudo apt-get install notify-osd`